# ASP.NET MVC4 with Entity Framework 6 to call a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, report, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure to display report in ASP.NET MVC project using Entity framework, this procedure is make for read purpose. I searched all tutorial but i didnt find any relevant example or relevant information that how to read stored procedure and display report in MVC project.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below step.

1. right Click on .edmx file.
2. Choose Update Model from database.
3. Add new stored procedure and refresh store procedure and ok.
4. again right Click on .edmx file.
5. Add New -> Import function.
6. Add function name and choose stored procedure and ok.

Comment: Refer this blog its provide full example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application

Comment: Refer other this blog :http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-7

Answer (score 0):

1. Explore server explorer `ctrl+alt+s' in visual studio.
2. Point to stored procedure
3. Open entity designer, You must have a designer(typically a database shadow copy) in Models folder. With extension `.edmx`
4. Drag procedure in `functions area` in desinger.

**To call procedure-**
Name of entityClass for example-

```
MyDbContext db= new MyDbContext();

//calling procedure
db.sp_myprocedure()
```

same way is for tables-

```
db.myTable();
```

Comment: can i get complete small example?